# Converting CFform tag into JavaScript using Jquery - Adobe Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, coldfusion, adobe

I have a CFform that is dynamically populated by a query but it is written using coldfusion tags. I want to convert it to Javascript and use the `<script>`tag. What would be the best way to do this? Would this even be possible with Coldfusion?

```
<h3>Car Names</h3>
<cfquery name="carbrands" > 
SELECT *
FROM carcompany
WHERE cartype_id = 6
</cfquery>
<cfform name="mycars" action="?????.cfm"> 

<cfselect name="carbrandsearch" 
query="carbrands" 
value="car_name" 
display="car_name">
</cfselect>
```

Comment: What have you tried? You can use `<select>` tag and `<cfloop query="carbrands">` to show `<option>`.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense.  The `<cfselect>` tag processes server side and jQuery processes client side.  Rephrase the question on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Question edited. Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way

Comment: The edit does not clarify the question.  A google search on `use javascript to create html elements` yields many results that shows that this is possible, but unless this is an academic exercise in jquery, attempting to do so seems unnecessarily complicated.  Did you notice that 4 people agreed with @rrk's comment?